# how to split first and last name in string array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have an array contains 15 full names, how do I break it into 2 arrays(first and last name) below is the method for my full name array

```
public static void readData(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    x = new Scanner(new File(file));
    //count number of names in the array
    int n = 0;
    while(x.hasNextLine()) {
        n++;
        x.nextLine();
    }
    //open another scanner to avoid null
    Scanner x1 = new Scanner(new File(file));
    name = new String[n];
    //get the array and print 
    for(int i = 0; i < name.length; i++ ) 
        name[i] = x1.nextLine();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
}
```

Comment: Create two arrays.  When you read the `String` from the file, split on the delimiter, I assume which is a "space", then add each element to the corresponding arrays

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you opening "another scanner to avoid null"? Seems entirely unnecessary.

Comment: Why are you reading this into an array at all? Just split and print in one pass. Also you leak not one but two file handles!

Comment: @Carcigenicate Looking at the code, they are trying to determine the number of lines in the file ahead of time ... They'd need to reset the `Scanner` to the start of the file, which is why I assume they're using two scanners, but not closing either ... and generally making a mess (and I doubt it would be a NPE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File contains 15 full names like this:

```
Max Frei
Stephen King
Agatha Christie
```

How to read:

```
final int total = 15;
String[] firstNames = new String[total];
String[] lastNames = new String[total];

try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("file"))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        firstNames[i] = scan.next();
        lastNames[i] = scan.next();
    }
}

// firstNames: Max, Stephen, Agatha
// lastNames: Frei, King, Christie
```

Comment: I also want to make sure that I understood this correctly. The key is to use scan,next() instead of nextLine(). When you do scan.next() it will assign the first name to firstName, then the next one to lastName, then repeat the cycle in for-loop, so my String[] name is actually irrelevant in this case. Is that correct?

Comment: nextLine() to read whole line, next() to read until next delimiter